# Convert crt and key to pfx using pure C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Without using any 3rd party libraries, how can you convert a .crt and .key to .pfx using pure c# code only ?

I am already familiar with how to do this on command line with openssl.  I am looking for a solution that uses only what is available within the .NET framework 4.0-4.5.2 .

To clarify on what no 3rd party libraries means, examples of 3rd party libraries follows:

- BouncyCastle - library
- openssl - command line util or embed
- makecert - command line util